# Was this Stargate SG-1 martial arts training montage inspired by The Karate Kid?

Tags: stargate-sg1, inspiration, jaffa

Was the *Stargate SG-1* episode "Affinity" (S8E7) martial arts training montage inspired by *The Karate Kid*? Just wondering if anyone else was getting a Karate Kid vibe during the scene where Teal'c started teaching Krista Lok'nel?

Comment: Wow. I had forgotten how bad this episode was. Like, entirely erased it from my memory.

Comment: Watching it, it looks more like a generic *'[training a teenager in how to do kata](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-1njO9fc8sA)' montage